# How to display a QMessageBox centered over its parent in PyQt4?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I'm trying to display a QMessageBox centered over its parent, but it appears to display over its parent's parent. The following code generates 4 push buttons in a 2x2 grid. When a button is clicked, I'd like the corresponding message box to show centered on the button that was clicked (ie, the parent). However, it always shows up in the middle of the containing widget.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class ClickHandler(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ClickHandler, self).__init__(parent)

    def onClicked(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        print sender

        QtGui.QMessageBox.information(sender, 'onClicked', 'Using static method')

        mb = QtGui.QMessageBox(sender)
        mb.setWindowTitle('onClicked')
        mb.setText('Using object and exec')
        mb.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    ch = ClickHandler()

    layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    for i in xrange(4):
        pb = QtGui.QPushButton('button %d' % i)
        pb.clicked.connect(ch.onClicked)
        layout.addWidget(pb, i // 2, i % 2)

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.setLayout(layout)
    w.resize(600, 600)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

According to the QMessageBox docs:

> parent is passed to the QDialog constructor

According to the QDialog docs:

> if it has a parent, its default location is centered on top of the parent

Not sure what I am doing wrong or what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the rest of the [paragraph](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdialog.html):

> Note that QDialog (an any other widget that has type Qt::Dialog) uses
>   the parent widget slightly differently from other classes in Qt. A
>   dialog is always a top-level widget, but if it has a parent, its
>   default location is centered on top of the **parent's top-level widget**
>   (if it is not top-level itself). It will also share the parent's
>   taskbar entry.

In your case the *parent* would be `sender`, and the *parent's top-level widget* would be the widget defined as `w`

Comment: Thank you. That statement is in the 'Detailed Description', but is not repeated in the constructor docs, which is where I copied my quote from. Need to read all of the manual next time. I guess I will need to write custom code to handle this case.